# Makefile for mixed C/C++ sources

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Suppose I have the following setup

```
CPPSRC+=path1/foo.cpp
CPPSRC+=path2/main.cpp

CSRC+=path3/zoo.c
CSRC+=path4/bar.c
```

I want to produce all object files `.o` into `build/` folder (so I supposingly need both pathsubst and pattern matching).

I also need the `.cpp` to be compiled with `g++` and related `CXXFLAGS`, whereas the `.c` need to be compiled with `gcc` and simplier `CFLAGS`.

I've come this far:

```
CPPOBJ := $(CPPSRC:%.cpp=%.o)
COBJ := $(CSRC:%.c=%.o)
OBJ := $(COBJ) $(CPPOBJ)
BUILTOBJ := $(addprefix $(BUILD_PATH)/,$(notdir $(OBJ)))

$(APP): $(OBJ)
    [...]

$(CPPOBJ): %.o: %.cpp
    @echo "[g++" $(BUILD_PATH)$(notdir $@)"]"
    $(SILENT)$(GPP) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $(BUILD_PATH)$(notdir $@)

$(COBJ): %.o: %.c
    @echo "[gcc " $(BUILD_PATH)$(notdir $@)"]"
    $(SILENT)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $(BUILD_PATH)$(notdir $@)
```

but cannot get to reach `$(COBJ): %.o: %.c` prerequisite (in short the `.c` sources do not get compiled).

How to?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to achieve using gmake's pattern rules is impossible because you're losing path information when you strip the source subdirectory from the object file.
So a generic pattern rule like `%.o: %.cpp` won't ever know that to compile `build/foo.o` it needs to look in `path1/foo.cpp`.
Not to mention the increased possibility of a naming conflict.

You can solve it by recreating the subdirectory structure under `build/`, i.e. compile `path1/foo.cpp` to `build/path1/foo.o`, etc.

Once that's sorted, gmake is smart enough to resolve seemingly ambiguous rules, i.e. it will have no problem at all compiling a mix of `.c` and `.cpp` files, like in the example below:

```
APP = app
BUILD_PATH = build
CPPOBJ := $(CPPSRC:%.cpp=%.o)
COBJ := $(CSRC:%.c=%.o)
OBJ := $(COBJ) $(CPPOBJ)
BUILTOBJ := $(addprefix $(BUILD_PATH)/,$(OBJ))

$(APP): $(BUILTOBJ)
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -o $@ $(BUILTOBJ) $(LDLIBS)    

$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

$(BUILD_PATH)/%.o: %.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

How naive of me.. because I did have the .o files in the original path (not in `build/`) and my `clean:` only removed the `build/` path, the `.c` prerequisites where never invoked and `.o` where not generated nor placed in the `build/` folder.

Indeed my trick tried to fool make by making it produce the `.o` file in a position different than what prerequisites defined.

Minor addon: I don't need to land to the makefile with separated C/C++ sources lists; I can achieve separation with the following:

```
CPPSRC:=$(filter %.cpp,$(SRC))
CSRC:=$(filter %.c,$(SRC))
CPPOBJ:= $(CPPSRC:%.cpp=%.opp)
COBJ:= $(CSRC:%.c=%.o)
OBJ:= $(COBJ) $(CPPOBJ)
BUILTOBJ:= $(addprefix $(BUILD_PATH)/,$(notdir $(OBJ)))
```